# How to use WCF in Silverlight modules which using Prism 4.0 for Integration

Tags: silverlight, wcf, prism

I have two seperate silverlight4.0 projects,among which one is the main project which will call the second one.
Currently am accomplishing this is through uri reference, but I need to integrate these projects using Prism4.0.

My actual problem is that, I can call my module project from my main project(shell), but not the WCF service that my module project is using.

Is there any solution to load the WCF service in module project using Prism in main project(shell)

Answer (score 0):

The client side of a WCF service is effectively just a library, not a module.

You need to create a PRISM module that simply links in that library (or has had a service reference added to that Module).

The assumption then is that all communication to your WCF library is only through that module, (or interfaces that module registers).

Answer (score 0):

I got it when I specified the endpoint of WCF service that I used in module project in the ServiceReference.ClientConfig file in my main project(Shell)

So in initial load itself it is getting the required endpoint.

Now it is working fine.